# Bash error 127 "nx: command not found" on pipeline, even though nx is installed in node_modules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When creating a pipeline, the [nx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nx) node module is not working:

```
jobs:
  - job: Test

    steps:
      - script: npm i
        displayName: npm install

      - script: nx --version
        displayName: Check nx
```

Resulting in the error: `line 1: nx: command not found`.

I can make it work using: `node node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js --version`.

But since I have several commands for nx that need to be performed, adding the `node node_modules...` becomes a bit verbose.

A possibility would perhaps be adjusting the PATH on the agents machine:

```
  steps:
  - script: |
      # Add the path to nx to the PATH environment variable
      export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/node_modules/nx/bin
      # Now you can use 'nx' directly
      nx --version
    displayName: 'Run nx command'
```

But that also seems a bit odd. Usually you do that only once on a machine. But now you do that on every run.

Is there a recommended way for this?

Comment: **npm install** does not install your packages globally, then you cannot call **nx** directly, instead you must use **npx nx**. If you want to call it directly without **npx**,  remove **nx** dependency from your package.json and install nx globally with **npm install nx -g** then you will be able to use **nx** directly.